# How to implement card layout as in new Google Play

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I would like to implement the Androidy list tile layout like the new Google Play below:

[image: new Google Play list layout]
I don't necessarily need to implement the exact content, only the tile-like layout of the list items. Does anyone know what attributes I should set, such as color, margin, and how to set a very subtle shadow below each item?

I have the following listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cardList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    android:cacheColorHint="@null"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:listSelector="@android:drawable/selector" />
```

and selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"
        android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/default"/>

</selector>
```

But it still does not work. Where could be the problem?

Comment: You will found its too easy soon after completing ListView chapter from any book.

Comment: Please understand this is more of a design question, not technical difficulties I'm having.

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

Comment: @Neoh then show us your homework and let us know [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @PareshMayani Homework done. See edit. This is how question should be answered.

Comment: So, if people want to see the solution posted by @Neoh, just click on the "edited" button and scroll a bit down...

Answer (score 2):

It's a basic `ListView` where each item is implemented using a `CustomAdapter`. Take a look at this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: This question is no longer needed. Please remove your answer as the post cannot be removed if it is answered. Thank you.

Comment: if you get the answer then why did you attempt to remove question? People help each other on this site, it's a bit of selfish to remove your question after you had your problem solved.

Comment: I used to found the solution but I was not allowed to post it because the question was closed. Neither was I allowed to edit the question to  include what I have found, some moderator said I cannot post answer under the question. I've attempted everything to reopen the question but there were not enough votes to reopen it.

Comment: how about putting a flag? Maybe you put it as a comment on question rather than as an answer thus you weren't allowed to put it, anyway editing question with multiple 'a's doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: I thought about putting it in comment but a comment can only be a short note, while my answer is anything but. I wanted to upload multiple images and have multiple paragraphs. In the end I felt that if the moderators were not willing to accept my question, I have to close the current one and ask another question in a more specific way. Those people just couldn't appreciate what I was really asking here and has declared it as invalid question.